# Friction during ball backspin and overspin

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, friction, rotational-kinematics

I already know sliding friction of ball on a flat table and rolling resistance of it.

How do I know coefficient of friction value when the ball has backspin with some angular velocity $\omega$? And also when it overspins (spinning faster than it would when rolling).

Also, we consider a ball with sidespin (spin around z axis), but with no spin around other axes sliding?

Also, does sidespin affect the coefficient of friction at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The friction experienced by the ball/rolling object experiencing backspin or topspin will be the sum of sliding friction and rolling friction. This is because extra spin on the ball is just a linear combination of sliding and rolling. Putting sidespin will not affect the friction as long as it is perpendicular to the direction of motion.

Answer (score 0):

The coefficient of dry friction is in general independent of the speed and therefore also of direction. Front/back spin will lead to forward acceleration/deceleration. Vertical spin will have no effect on forward motion.

Comment: Question was different. Let's say I have a force F=µmg, where µ is sliding coefficient of friction. Which is acting to transfer angular velocity into translational velocity. Does this µ change depending on the type of spin (backspin/overspin) of the ball?

Comment: What I read in one research that "a spinning disk experiences less friction and slides farther than a disk without rotation" [link](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=QKlPihGzeUAC&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=%22a+spinning+disk+experiences+less+friction%22&source=bl&ots=ZqSyWv5m_C&sig=G1ftQAJNG_l2yKp4v4tNLsxeAMw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihiKGyt9LbAhVFSZoKHYqUCIoQ6AEIOTAC#v=onepage&q=%22a%20spinning%20disk%20experiences%20less%20friction%22&f=false). So possibly you were not correct that "Vertical spin will have no effect on forward motion."